# How to dump(collect) all the group policies in a domain?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain, domain-controller

I want to collect all the GPOs in a domain , for reviewing settings. How many ways are there to do it. I used Get-GPOREPORT in Powershell, but it gave a comprehensive html file, is these a way to collect and review the group policies individually? Please let me know your suggestions and questions if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
Foreach($Policy In Get-ChildItem \\$((Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot)\sysvol\$((Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot)\Policies)
{
    Get-GPO -Guid $Policy.Name | Select *

    # Now you have an individual GPO. Do something useful with it.        
    #
    # DisplayName      : Terminate Idle and Disconnected RDP Sessions
    # DomainName       : CONTOSO.COM
    # Owner            : CONTOSO\Domain Admins
    # Id               : f8858a61-91b4-4d1f-8d64-be6fa0252680
    # GpoStatus        : AllSettingsEnabled
    # Description      : 
    # CreationTime     : 1/20/2014 11:57:50 AM
    # ModificationTime : 6/3/2014 10:02:38 AM
    # UserVersion      : AD Version: 0, SysVol Version: 0
    # ComputerVersion  : AD Version: 4, SysVol Version: 4
    # WmiFilter        : 
    # Computer         : Microsoft.GroupPolicy.ComputerConfiguration
    # User             : Microsoft.GroupPolicy.UserConfiguration
}
```

Edit: Duhhh I did it the hard way instead of just using `Get-GPO -All`.  :)

Comment: Save yourself the second `Get-ADDomain` lookup with `"\\$(($d = (Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot))\sysvol\$d\Policies"` ;-)